# Trying to install Eclipse plugins from Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.
I'm running Eclipse for Java version 4.52.

For Java,
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

I can open the marketplace and many of the plugins will load.
But, when I search for something it will start querying and freeze there.
I've tried waiting thirty minutes and have tried doing this twice, but still not working.

edit: 
I resolved the issue. I can drag and drop the plugins I want to install into Eclipse!

Comment: is it using openjdk which comes bundled by default in ubuntu? if so, try to reinstall eclipse using oracle jdk (I think eclipse won't allow you to switch the JVM once it's installed, you'll have to install it again setting JAVA_HOME and PATH to the oracle jdk first)

Comment: you may find some interesting debug info at help->about eclipse->installation details->configuration->view error log

Comment: @Leo I'm using Oracle's jdk

Comment: in this case pls check the error log, if possible, post it here (or use pastebin if it's too long)

Comment: @Leo here's the [error log](http://pastebin.com/RNGCpG21)

Comment: I think this may be the cause -- !MESSAGE Server â€˜org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.serverâ€™ failed with exception: Service Temporarily Unavailable. ; version: 1.100.0.v20160217-0435
!STACK 0
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: @Leo does this mean the marketplace is globally down or something is wrong with say my router or firewall?

Comment: I can't tell, but since you can list the plugins, it seems to be a temporary problem in the server, not on your firewall or router.

Comment: many times, you can directly access the plugin manufacturer site and download it from there, not using the marketplace.